# RSpec can't define singleton error when trying to mock gets and puts for Hash Elements

Tags: hash, io, mocking, rspec2, ruby-1.9.3

I have a Book Model which is a ruby script that assigns prices to certain predefined Book titles mentioned in the program. Here's how the book model looks:-

```
class Book

  attr_accessor :books  
  def initialize books
    puts "Welcome to setting book price program"
    @books = books
  end

  def get_prices
    puts "Please enter appropriate price for each book item:-"
    count = 0
    @books = @books.inject({}) { |hash, book|
      print "#{book.first}: "
      price = STDIN.gets.chomp
      while (price !~ /^[1-9]\d*$/ && price != "second hand")
        puts "Price can't be 0 or a negative integer or in decimal format or alphanumeric. \nPlease input appropriate price in integer"
        price = STDIN.gets.chomp #gets.chomp - throws error
      end
      price == "second hand" ? price = "100" : price #takes a default price
      hash[book.first] = price.to_i
      hash
    }
  end

end

books = {"The Last Samurai" => nil,
         "Ruby Cookbook" =>  nil,
         "Rails Recipes" =>  nil,
         "Agile Development with Rails" =>  nil,
         "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows" =>  nil}


book_details = Book.new(books)
book_details.get_prices
puts "\n*******Books Details:#{book_details.books}******\n"
```

I'm trying to write a test case that checks for correct input of price for each book item. If the price is entered inappropriately, it should ask the user to re enter the price correctly. The program does this fine. But I'm facing difficulties when I'm trying to mock this behavior using RSpec.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Book do

  before :each do
    books = {"The Last Samurai" => nil,
         "Ruby Cookbook" =>  nil,
         "Rails Recipes" =>  nil,
         "Agile Development with Rails" =>  nil,
         "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows" =>  nil}
    @book = Book.new(books)
  end

  describe "#new" do
    it "Should be an instance of the Book" do
      @book.should be_an_instance_of Book
    end
  end

  describe "#getprice" do
    it "Should get the price in the correct format or else return appropriate error" do
      puts "\n************************************************************************\n"
      book_obj = @book
      STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).and_return("Welcome to setting book price program")
      book_obj.get_prices.should_not be_nil
      book_obj.books["The Last Samurai"].stub!(:gets) {"40"} #trying to set the value for one book using Hash
      book_obj.books["The Last Samurai"].should == 40 #verifying the value set for a particular key is accurate
    end
  end

end
```

You can even [clone this code](https://github.com/boddhisattva/book) from Github to try this from your end. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and rspec 2.11.0

```
The error that I'm getting currently is:-

Failures:

  1) Book#getprice Should get the price in the correct format or else return appropriate error
     Failure/Error: book_obj.books["The Last Samurai"].stub!(:gets) {"40"} #trying to set the value for one book using Hash
     TypeError:
       can't define singleton
     # ./spec/book_spec.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 7.61 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/book_spec.rb:21 # Book#getprice Should get the price in the correct format or else return appropriate error
```

**UPDATED QUESTION**

For *bad user input*, with the below test case I'm getting the following error. How can I correctly handle this? I've tried a couple of options, but they all seem to fail. Please see the comment for each option as part of the spec snippet.

```
 it "Incorrect input format should return error message asking user to re input" do
      puts "\n************************************************************************\n"
      book_obj = @book
      STDIN.stub(:gets) { "40abc" }

      #book_obj.get_prices.should be_nil --> adding this line of code goes into an infinite loop with the error message below
      #Price cannot be 0 or a negative integer or in decimal format or alphanumeric. \nPlease input appropriate duration in integer\n

      STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).and_return("Price cannot be 0 or a negative integer or in decimal format or alphanumeric. \nPlease input appropriate duration in integer\n")

      #the below two tests fails with syntax error - don't seem that easy to figure out what's going wrong

      #STDOUT.should_receive("Price cannot be 0 or a negative integer or in decimal format or alphanumeric. \nPlease input appropriate duration in integer\n")
      #STDOUT.should == "Price cannot be 0 or a negative integer or in decimal format or alphanumeric. \nPlease input appropriate duration in integer\n"
    end


Failures:

  1) Book#getprice Incorrect input format should return error message asking user to re input
     Failure/Error: STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).and_return("Price cannot be 0 or a negative integer or in decimal format or alphanumeric. \nPlease input appropriate duration in integer\n")
       (#<IO:0x00000001c7b298>).puts(any args)
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times
     # ./spec/book_spec.rb:40:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I would really appreciate any guidance how to get this right. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run the spec with the `--backtrace` flag, you'll see that the error is raised on https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/v2.13.0/lib/rspec/mocks/method_double.rb#L140, where rspec-mocks is trying to get the singleton class of the object being stubbed or mocked. This would work fine with instances of most classes, but there is an error in the spec.

The code sends `gets` to `STDIN`, but the spec is trying to stub `gets` on `book_obj.books["The Last Samurai"]`, which is an `int` at the time, and you can't get a singleton from an `int`:

```
$ irb
1.9.3-p392 :001 > class << 1; self; end
TypeError: can't define singleton
        from (irb):1
    from /Users/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

If I understand correctly, you want to make two changes. First, move the last lines of the script to a separate file that doesn't get loaded when you run the spec e.g. bin/books (it can require book.rb and then add those lines).

Next, remove the line that stubs `gets` on `book_obj.books["The Last Samurai"]` and add a line that stubs `gets` on `STDIN` instead, *before* the line that invokes `get_prices` (which is when the interaction w/ `STDIN` happens):

```
STDIN.stub(:gets) { "40" }
book_obj.get_prices.should_not be_nil
```

That will at least get your spec passing.

In general, code that deals w/ `STDIN` and `STDOUT` directly is hard to spec at the object level because testing tools like rspec, minitest, etc, all use `STDOUT` to present their information, so you end up with a lot of confusing noise in the shell. I'd recommend either changing the design to inject input/output streams to the book class (which can be `STDIN` and `STDOUT` when you run the script, but test doubles when you run rspec), or use a tool like [aruba](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba), which is designed to spec interactive shell scripts.

Comment: First off, really appreciate you trying to help me work around this. Your suggestion did work to help handle user input given in the correct format. I'm still not able to figure my way around bad user input inspite of trying a couple of combinations(please see **updated question** with details of code and error). I just have one more thing to ask, please excuse my ignorance if I'm missing something.. while trying to stub stub gets on book_obj.books["The Last Samurai"] I'm just trying to assign a value to key, so I'm really not understanding what is int out there.. please explain..Thanks

Comment: The infinite loop is because of the `while` loop in `get_prices`. You'll need to stub both the bad input and the good input to get past that e.g. `STDIN.stub(:gets) { "40abc" }; STDIN.stub(:gets) { "40" };`.

Comment: The syntax error is because you're saying `STDOUT` should receive a String, but it should receive `puts` _with_ a String e.g. `STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("this string")`. What you have is trying to look for a method named "Price cannot be 0 or a negative integer or in decimal format or alphanumeric. \nPlease input appropriate duration in integer\n", thus the syntax error.

Comment: David, Based on your suggestion for the bad input spec I've updated the file. Kindly have a look at the changes [here](https://github.com/boddhisattva/book/commit/1e0425d316175d6cbe6472aa70118e7185b8aa48). I'm still getting the infinite loop and I guess the spec isn't coming to the the line(that's line no. 33 in the actual code shared via link) where I can check the below condition - STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("this string") May be I need to handle the infinite loop properly first, but I'm somehow not yet able to get there. Thank you.

Comment: You have to write both stubs _before_ any calls to `get_prices`.

Comment: I've tried that in this [commit](https://github.com/boddhisattva/book/commit/a345c4c2b5a9347576970cf36aba452b27f742ac#commitcomment-3686453). I'm still getting an error. I've mentioned the details of the error as a comment to that commit. I'm wondering if we stub the gets before we call get_prices, how should it work because in the actual code we are taking user input only after calling get_prices. I do understand that in the case of the infinite loop also we are stubbing the gets before calling get_prices.

Comment: What's really confusing me is this flow seems different from the actual code flow. I don't know which is the right way to test this scenario.

Comment: I just observed, if one stubs gets with an incorrect input and then with a correct input, the method call get_prices will take the latest gets value thus STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("Price cannot be 0 or a negative integer or in decimal format or alphanumeric. \nPlease input appropriate duration in integer\n") doesn't pass. But a question that still remains is how to make it pass..?

Comment: I wanted to comment here because I made a really stupid mistake that I wasted time trying to figure out. I got the same error message as OP. 

It doesn't answer the OP's issue, but it might help someone else. I was (stupidly) trying to create a stub on a symbol instead of the original object:

`allow(:object).to receive(:method)`

when it should have been: `allow(object).to receive(:method)`

Comment: Thank you @JoeEdgar, It saved a lot of time for me.